# Postgres expand JSON with unkown keys

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to expand a specific row in my table which has a json column with the followingstructure:

```
 id|column1      |
---|-------------|
id1|{nested json}|
id2|{nested json}|
```

Structure of nested JSON is as follows:

```
{"random_key_1":{"
               known_key_1":"value",
               "known_key_2":"value"
              },
"random_key_2":{"
               known_key_1":"value",
               "known_key_2":"value"
              },
...
```

I want expand a single row into following format:

```
my_column_name |known_key_1 |known_key2|
---------------|-----------|----------|
random_key_1   |  value    |  values  |
random_key_2   |  value    |  values  |
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978846/postgres-expand-json-column-into-rows

Comment: Haha! I tired to build my logic based on this post but the nested part is something that postgres doesn't like :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in [json_each](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) method to expand your outermost JSON into rows without knowing what the keys are. From that point, you can build the known columns directly.

```sql
SELECT col1.key AS my_column_name, 
       col1.value->>'known_key_1' AS known_key_1, 
       col1.value->>'known_key_2' AS known_key_2 
FROM main_table, json_each(column1) col1;

 my_column_name | known_key_1 | known_key_2
----------------+-------------+-------------
 random_key_1   | value1      | value2
 random_key_2   | value3      | value4
```